# Is it possible to work with FTPS under PHP using stream context?

Tags: php, security, ssl, ftp, ftps

I learned that using **ftps** (´ftp_ssl_connect()´) under PHP for Windows is tough. You are asked to enter a long journey of building your own binaries to include Open SSL... I found advice on [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) as a replacement (but getting openssl.cnf right to support peer validation sounds pretty hard to me, too...).

Then I hit [this article](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/tls-peer-verification#tls_peer_verification) and its pleasingly simple example including working peer validation (to avoid Man-in-the-middle-Attacks) drew my attention to streams:

```
$uri = 'https://www.bankofamerica.com/';
$ctx = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => true, // important
    'cafile' => '/hard/path/to/cacert.pem',
    'CN_match' => 'www.bankofamerica.com'
]]);
$html = file_get_contents($uri, FALSE, $ctx); // we are good
```

However, is this useful for ftp connections? **Can I also use peer-validated stream contexts to open ftps streams?** [The php manual hints](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ftp.php), ssl context options also apply to sftp, but lacks further guidance.

*So I am wildly guessing:*

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(['ftps' => [
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'cafile' => 'd:/sandbox/mycerts.pem',
    'CN_match' => 'ftp-12345678.mywebhoster.com'
]]);
```

Right? Wrong? User+Password as options now? And then what? User/Password now? Or later? I am clueless...

- How do I scan the remote ftp directory contents to start with?
- How to I upload or download a file from an ftp server?

Is any of that even possible? (A few lines of code would be very helpful....) Or are streams only good for singular file access?

*Update*:
Curl might do what I want (including peer validation and directory lsiting) [as shown in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698567/444255). Will examine later this week...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Will this work?

> Can I also use peer-validated stream contexts to open ftps streams?

Yes. The *ftps* stream wrapper utilizes the same SSL context options as the *https* wrapper and will be available as long as you have the openssl extension enabled in your PHP build. You can verify if the *ftps* wrapper is available by checking the output from [`stream_get_wrappers()`](https://www.php.net/stream_get_wrappers) like so:

```
<?php
print_r(stream_get_wrappers());
```

If you have ext/openssl enabled in your php build you'll see *ftps* listed in the output alongside the other available stream wrappers.

### How do I assign the SSL context options?

> So I am wildly guessing

You're really close! The only thing you need to change in your code is to replace `"ftps"` with `"ssl"` as shown here:

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'cafile' => 'd:/sandbox/mycerts.pem',
    'CN_match' => 'ftp-12345678.mywebhoster.com'
]]);
```

Regardless of whether you're using *https*, *ftps* or any other stream wrapper the context options governing SSL/TLS encryption are always stored in the `"ssl"` key.

### Where do I put the user/password?

> Right? Wrong? User+Password as options now? And then what? User/Password now? Or later? I am clueless...

The *ftp* and *ftps* stream wrappers both expect the username and password in the URI as shown here:

```
<?php
$ftpPath = 'ftps://username:password@example.com';
```

Don't be thrown off by our specification of the user/pass in cleartext here. The stream wrapper will only send the username and password *after* an encrypted connection is established.

### Putting it all together

The [`opendir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) family of functions supports the *ftp* wrapper (since PHP 5.0). You use these functions the same way you would with local filesystem paths:

```
<?php
$ctx = stream_context_create(['ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'cafile' => 'd:/sandbox/mycerts.pem',
    'CN_match' => 'ftp-12345678.mywebhoster.com'
]]);
$dirHandle = opendir('ftps://username:password@example.com/', $ctx);
while (($file = readdir($dirHandle)) !== false) {
    echo "filename: $file\n";
}
closedir($dirHandle);
```

### Note on SSL/TLS name matching

If it doesn't work initially you should test without passing the additional context `$ctx` containing the SSL options. The CN (common name) field of the server's certificate must match the `"CN_match"` value you specify (with limited wildcard matching for subdomains). Also, prior to the forthcoming PHP-5.6 release there is no support for matching names against the Subject Alternative Name field in the remote party's certificate. Unless you're working with a development preview for 5.6 you won't have this capability (SAN matching) and the peer verification routine will fail if the server relies on SAN.

Comment: ✰ Great wisdom directly from the source! Thank you so much! Some of this should go a bit more outspoken into the php docs... (especially for all those who will run with despair into `ftp_ssl_connect()`)

Comment: @Fronker Glad I could help :) And yes, I have a *ton* of documentation updating to do between now and the 5.6 release.